# combine two queries from different classes into one query in swift

Tags: swift, join, parse-platform

I want to combine two queries from different classes into one query in swift 
like

```js
var query = PFQuery(className: "Videos")
var query2 = PFQuery(className: "Relationship")
query.whereKey("addedby", notEqualTo: currentUser!)
query2.whereKey("toUser", notEqualTo: currentUser!)

// i want to join them in 
// should be like query3 = query + query2
```

Comment: I'm trying to search same thing . Did you find anything?

Comment: I choose alternative approach  , i had to put it query into a query    query1 { query2} you know what i mean :D

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 2, you can use this:

```
let query3 : PFQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([query,query2])
```

Comment: NA it dosent work  2016-01-09 14:55:32.379 ParseStarterProject[1939:273745] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'All sub queries of an `or` query should be on the same class.'
*** First throw call stack: